# What is endpoint to access a user's Office 365 group using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, office365-restapi

I am using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups but it needs admin privilege. Does anyone know how to get the groups assigned to sign-in user?

Answer (score 0):

For an app to read or manage an Office 365 group, it does require an administrator to grant those permissions to the application.  Once granted, the app can query for the O365 groups that the signed in user is a member of.  For more information please see the scenarios section in the permissions topic here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes#permission-scope-scenarios.

Also the front page overview of the Microsoft Graph documentation has a table with common queries: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/overview.  The one you want (to get the groups for the signed in user) is:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf/$/microsoft.graph.group?$filter=groupTypes/any(a:a%20eq%20'unified')
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks  for your help. The am trying to get the files that belong to groups that the signed-in user is part of. In the one drive for business the groups are displayed under "group" on left side of the page. So if I understand correctly, I would need to create a consent screen that an admin of the organization would need to use in order to make the feature available for all users within the org?

Comment: If there User is a member of a Group, the Files they have access to should show up as files shared with them. Take a look at https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_sharedwithme